# Having a Date And DateTime Comparison problem in my SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Been testing this over and over, and it fails at the date comparison.(`item.id_type` seems to work fine).

`request.date` has the datatype `DATETIME`.

```
SELECT request.id, request.date, request.total_price,
    item.cod_GERFIP,item.price,item.name,request_item.quantity,
    section.name AS section,user.firstname,user.lastname   

FROM ((((`request_item` 
INNER JOIN `request` ON  request_item.id_request = request.id)
INNER JOIN `item` ON request_item.id_item = item.cod_GERFIP)
INNER JOIN `user` ON request.id_user = user.id) 
INNER JOIN `section` ON user.section = section.id) 

WHERE request.date >= '2019-01-09' AND request.date <= '2019-01-10'  
    AND item.id_type = '1' 
ORDER BY request.date DESC
```

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What error are you getting? and is the request.date actually a date?

Comment: You could try explicitly converting your date field to a date format - WHERE convert(date,request.date) >= '2019-01-09'

Comment: jimmy8ball THANK you, it worked, i thought i dint need any convertion since request.date was datetime

Comment: My comment actually substantiates what @Joel Coehoorn is explaining below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, because you haven't explained what or how the query fails, but to my eyes this condition does not look correct:

```
 request.date <= '2019-01-10'
```

It's a common mistake to expect a condition like this, when used a part of a range, to include all records where the date part of a datetime field is `2019-01-10`. That is, if we have an example value in the database of 1 PM on the same day (`2019-01-10 13:00:00`), the expectation is this value will narrow to match the `2019-01-10` literal in the query, the two values will be equal, and so it will meet the condition.

*It does work this way.*

Instead, the `2019-01-10` literal in the query is *widened* to a full DateTime, that looks more like this: `2019-01-10 00:00:00.000`. Now the 1 PM value from the table is compared with this full date time, and it fails the condition.

It's much more common for a date range to compare using an *exclusive* upper bound set for one day in the future:

```
request.date < '2019-01-11'
```

Alternatively, you may be tempted to do this:

```
request.date <= '2019-01-10 23:59:59.999'
```

It will even work most of the time. Just be warned that in the (rare) case of leap seconds, you can still end up with incorrect results that way.

You may also be tempted to do something like this:

```
convert(date,request.date) <= '2019-01-10'
```

This works, but it's not recommended because it prevents the use of any index you might have on the `request.date` field, and that cuts at the core of database performance.

---

Or maybe the problem is even simpler. With the start of range at `2019-01-09`, maybe you wanted to get the records for exactly one day, and are surprised to see a few values from midnight on `2010-01-10`. Again, the solution is you want an *exclusive* boundary at the top of the range:

```
request.date < '2019-01-10'
```

As a complete side note to the question, I'm a very sad the SQL `BETWEEN` operator is inclusive at both end of the range. This may make sense for numeric or string data, but for date values defining an exclusive upper bound for the `BETWEEN` operator would have made much more sense.

Comment: I premuse the server im using is having some delays at updating, the convert method started giving error so returned to what i had and it worked, but i appreciate the help